# Defining arrays according to the id

Tags: php, arrays

I do not where to start bu I will be as precise as I can be. There are over 200 customer in the database. I use php.

I made 2 calculations and assigned new values into an array but the results of these calculations will be used in another calculation. When I click on the calculate button it should first take the data from the arrays ($snduz=array_values($array5)[0]; and $test=array_values($array4)[0]; and $snduz=array_values($array5)[1]; and $test=array_values($array4)[1]; so on) that belong to related id put that value into the formula and calculate.

When I put the arrays 1 by 1 it works e.g.

```
 $array5[] = ($sab1*(($test-$ort)/$sdsp)+$sab2); 

 $snduz=array_values($array5)[0];
 $snduz1=array_values($array5)[1];
 $snduz2=array_values($array5)[2];
    .....

$array4[] = ($tams*$enku)/$row4['sn'];  

$test=array_values($array4)[0];
$test1=array_values($array4)[1];
$test2=array_values($array4)[2];
    ...
```

but I want to get them calculated automatically

Comment: please add a tag for the programming language you're using. That will make it easier for others to provide a solution.

Comment: Use a for loop!? o.O

Comment: I just want to get the value belongs to that id. For example, I click on the id 55, I should get ($array5)[2] and ($array4)[2] together then I will put these values into another calculation.